# Rename a file in a zip file during Gradle build

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am using Gradle 6.8.2 with Java 8 on Windows 10 with WSL 2 Mint.

I would like to rename a file when it is added into the uber jar.

The problem lies with the LICENSE.txt files.  I would like to rename each ***LICENSE.text*** file to ***<lib_name_version >_LICENSE.txt***.  If I set the property to allow duplicates, then you lose which LICENSE.txt file goes with which library.  It'd be nice if you could apply a visitor when the files are being added to the uber jar.  I can get the name portion of the jar file without any problems.  Below is my *build.gradle* file.  I am upgrading/forking a library in Github.  I haven't add the publishing yet.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
version = '2.1.0003'
jar.archiveVersion = version
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

archivesBaseName = 'onvif-java-lib'
group = 'com.qed.aes.camera'

java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}

// task to list deprecated stuff in the compile
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    // Using/setting StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 eliminates a problem with UFT-8 on
    // Windows in NetBeans.  There are some characters that don't work in the UTF-8.
    options.encoding = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 
    options.deprecation = true
    options.compilerArgs += ['-Xlint:deprecation']
    options.compilerArgs += ['-Xlint:unchecked']
}

compileJava.options.encoding = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1

javadoc {
    options.encoding = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1
    options.tags = [ "date" ]
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
}

jar {
    archiveVersion = project.version
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'ONVIF Java Library',
            'Implementation-Version': archiveVersion,
            'Main-Class': 'org.me.javawsdiscovery.JavaWSDiscovery'
    }
    
    String libName;
    String newName;
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.findAll {
            it.name.endsWith('jar') && (!it.name.contains('javadoc')) && (!it.name.contains('sources'))
        }.collect { 
            libName = it.getName();
            libName = libName.substring(0,libName.indexOf(".jar"));
            zipTree(it) 
        }.each { tree ->
            tree.visit { file ->
                println file.class.getName()
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
   }
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:2.1.1'
    compileOnly group: 'jakarta.json', name: 'jakarta.json-api', version: '2.1.1', classifier:'sources'
    compileOnly group: 'jakarta.json', name: 'jakarta.json-api', version: '2.1.1', classifier:'javadoc'


    implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.15'
    compileOnly group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.15', classifier: 'sources'
    compileOnly group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.15', classifier: 'javadoc'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    // Original project page: https://www.javatuples.org/index.html
    // Library: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.flipkart.utils/javatuples/3.0/jar
    implementation 'com.flipkart.utils:javatuples:3.0'
    compileOnly 'com.flipkart.utils:javatuples:3.0:sources'
    compileOnly 'com.flipkart.utils:javatuples:3.0:javadoc'
}
```